# Docker running multiple Apache instances

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker

Here is what I am trying to do

- Setup a Docker container to run Ubuntu
- Link it to another container running Apache + PHP
- and yet one more running MariaDB + ReDis

Now I want to, say, allow three users to run their own virtual instance of Apache so I map Port 443 on each docker Apache container

docker run -p 808x:443 -d mysite

The whole lot is hosted on a DigitalOcean box with the IP pointed to by the domain example.com for which I have a wildcard SSL cert.

Questions

1. What am I lacking in this scheme to allow me to point each user to their own secure url. e.g. https:// example.com:808x?
2. I will be monitoring the various containers in the background with a view to terminating them after they have run for X minutes.
3. At this point I would like to save the MariaDB + ReDis container to a .tar archive for resuse when the same user attempts to use the system.  Would this be the right approach?
4. I am still a Docker newbie.  My reading thus far has turned up several admonitions regarding exposing ports on the host machine.  With what I have outlined I would be exposing several 808x ports.  What are the risks involved in doing this?

I would much appreciate any help here.

Comment: Docker doesn't "run Ubuntu". The 'ubuntu' image has a copy of Ubuntu userspace files, and you can run whatever you like within that. Given this, I don't understand what you first container is for.

Comment: A fully functional app stack inside a set of linked docker containers would require an OS a web server, a scripting language & a DB.  Run was an unfortunate choice of words.  docker pull ubuntu is what I really meant.

Comment: Could you elaborate your problem? I don't understand your actual problem. What have you tried and what problems did you run into?

Comment: I installed my wildcard cert in the Docker Apache container.  Originally the host machine did not run a server of any description at all.  I thought that might be the issue so I tried a config with a server bearing the WC cert on the host machine + on each of the Apache containers. Still no joy - I cannot reach the contained Apache instances on https:808x

Comment: You don't need to 'pull ubuntu' unless you need to run something directly on top of that image.  If you don't have this requirement, your first container would not exist and ubuntu (or debian, etc.), would be a base layer for the Apache/PHP container.